# How can I explicitly free numpy array memory?

Tags: python, numpy, memory-management

How can I explicitly free the memory associated with a `numpy` array?

As usual on Stackexchange, there are numerous questions with more-or-less the same title, but with no correct answer.

Here is an example of the problem:

```py
import numpy as np

big_arr = ...
def process_big_arr(arr: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
  big_intermediate_arr_1 = ... # some function of `arr`.
  del arr # This will not trigger garbage collection because a reference
  # to `big_arr` still exists in the outer scope.
  big_intermediate_arr_2 = ... # Memory error here, because I'm out of RAM.
  # I want the input array `arr` to be destroyed. I won't be using it again.
  big_output_arr = ...
  return big_output_arr
output = process_big_arr(big_arr)
```

I couldn't find in the `numpy` docs a function which *mutates* an array in such a way that it deallocates memory.

Is there any way to do this? Perhaps by editing the properties of the numpy array and changing its memory pointer or something?

Comment: The `resize` method might work to reduce its memory use.  Something like `arr.resize(10)`.  I haven't tried it.  `resize` only works in selective cases.

Comment: You cannot explicitly free memory in Python.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - feel free to elaborate and write an answer. However, I'm dubious of your statement. Python does include `ctypes` which I would have thought allows you to explicitly free memory somewhere. There are also Python modules which include methods to explicitly free underlying memory. It may work through a Python API, but that doesn't mean it isn't explicitly freeing memory.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than trying to explicitly free the memory of an object before its lifetime ends, it'd make more sense to restructure your code so the array's lifetime *does* end when you want it to.

For example, you can wrap your big array in a 1-element list, and pass the list around instead of holding multiple references to the array:

```
big_arr_wrapper = [...]
def process_big_arr(arr_wrapper):
    big_intermediate_arr_1 = do_something(big_arr_wrapper[0])
    arr_wrapper.clear()
    ...
```

That way, `arr_wrapper.clear()` removes the last reference to the original array, instead of leaving another reference lingering.

Comment: Is this really standard practice? I honestly don't think I've ever seen anything like this in the wild

Comment: @roganjosh: I don't think it's standard. Keeping data behind an extra level of indirection to help with memory management is something I've seen before in languages like C or C++, but I've never used this sort of technique before in Python.

Comment: I wonder whether we're missing too much from the operations that the OP wants to do and maybe it could be done in-place if they're just going to throw the original away. I think if I was confronted with this approach, I wouldn't at all understand why you're wrapping something in a list without the context of this question

Comment: @roganjosh: Writing a container type with a descriptive name and docstring could help, but in most cases, I'd probably try to find a different approach too. In-place operations, buying more RAM, algorithmic changes, working on disk...

Comment: That's a great idea, thank you. I'd prefer a more canonical solution, but this certainly helps me out of the jam.

Comment: @user2357112 - I'm already memory-mapping arrays where feasible, and using `out=...` keywords of `numpy` and `scipy` functions where available. I'm using `numexpr` to multithread code, and overwriting existing memory where I can. The system has over 1TB of RAM. I'm chunking intermediate operations to reduce the transient RAM requirement. Operations are performed on the GPU whenever feasible. Changing the algorithm fundamentally is an open research problem. It is an unfortunatetly frequent refrain on SO for contributors to unfairly criticise the question.

Comment: @Myridium are you suggesting that I "unfairly" criticised the question because you gave no details or what the operations actually are, and the best answer so far is non-standard in python (I have actually interacted with 2357112 a lot in the past and have upmost respect for their answers)? I haven't downvoted or close-voted the question, I simply made a statement. It's unfortunately a frequent problem on SO that people feel attacked or criticised when basic things are given scrutiny

Comment: @roganjosh - sorry, no I'm not suggesting that. I appreciate yours and user2357112's contribution. I just think the SO community is poisoned by a pervasive culture of trying to diagnose all question-askers as having an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The context behind what I'm doing is not relevant to the question. It's my responsibility as the question-asker to get to the root of the question and ask it in its purest form, so it is generic and relevant to as many people as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a test of my idea of using the `resize` method.

First try:

```
In [420]: def foo(arr):
     ...:     arr1 = np.zeros(10000)
     ...:     arr.resize(10)
     ...:     return arr1
     ...:     

In [421]: arr= np.arange(100000)

In [422]: foo(arr)
ValueError: cannot resize an array that references or is referenced
by another array in this way.
Use the np.resize function or refcheck=False
```

Retry:

```
In [423]: def foo(arr):
     ...:     arr1 = np.zeros(10000)
     ...:     arr.resize(10, refcheck=False)
     ...:     return arr1
     ...:     

In [424]: arr.size
Out[424]: 100000

In [425]: foo(arr)
Out[425]: array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.])

In [426]: _.shape
Out[426]: (10000,)

In [427]: arr.shape
Out[427]: (10,)
```

`getsizeof` confirms this new size.

I don't know how powerful the refcheck=false is.

### edit

If I make a `view` of `arr` before the resize, that array can have bad values

```
In [450]: arr= np.arange(100000)
In [451]: arr2 = arr[::2]
In [452]: foo(arr)
Out[452]: array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.])

In [453]: arr2
Out[453]: array([    0,     2,     4, ..., 99994, 99996, 99998])

In [454]: len(arr)
Out[454]: 10
In [455]: len(arr2)
Out[455]: 50000
In [456]: arr2[:10]
Out[456]: 
array([          0,           2,           4,           6,           8,
                10,          12,  1643397519, -1379233776, -1507574848])
```

So a function like this, or anything that one way of other mutates the argument, can have dangerous consequences if you aren't careful.  The `refcheck` for `resize` is there to protect us from ourselves.

Comment: I avoided mentioning this method, because it's unnecessary and *much* less safe than just making sure the array's lifetime ends at the right time. Screw up, and you can easily get arbitrary memory corruption, which might manifest as silently wrong results instead of anything obvious.

Comment: @user2357112 - can you give an example of how wrong memory addresses could be accessed after using this method?

Comment: @Myridium: Okay, let's say you use `resize`, and then later, you accidentally change the code so it saves a view of your big array before resizing it. That view is now a view of deallocated memory, which might be reused for arbitrary other things. Reads can return arbitrary garbage, and writes might write to anything. [Here's an example.](https://ideone.com/rnP81z)

Comment: @user2357112 - Isn't the kernel supposed to prevent writing to another process's memory? Neither approach is fully satisfying: (1) Memory indirection by introducing a new datastructure. (2) Forcing deallocation in spite of dangling references. Your approach (1) has the danger of leaving the memory allocated if there is a dangling reference, which can also result in difficult-to-diagnose problems.

Maybe the best way to handle this is by passing around a wrapping data structure that has a method which calls `arr.resize(0, refcheck=True)`. An exception will be thrown if references remain.

Comment: I've had to unmark this answer as accepted because `arr.resize(0, refcheck=False)` only works under some conditions, i.e. if the array 'owns its own data'. Maybe it's bugged, because when I load an array straight from disk which happens to be Fortran-ordered in memory, it doesn't have the `OWNDATA` flag set and so this method fails.

Comment: It's not so much the Fortran-order, but how it was constructed, the `OWNDATA` property.  `np.ones((10,10), order='F')` works, `np.arange(100).reshape(10,10)` doesn't.  A transpose doesn't own its data either.  But embedding the array in a list or some class may not help either, if the `base` has it's own reference(s).

Comment: @Myridium: Yeah, that's one of the other limitations. If your original array is actually a view, you can't `resize` it, and a lot more arrays are views than you might expect.

Comment: @Myridium: Instead of using `ndarray.resize` in a wrapper class, you could detect extra references with [`sys.getrefcount`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getrefcount). The expected refcount would be 2: 1 held by the wrapper, and 1 for the argument to `sys.getrefcount`. If there are any more references than that, something went wrong. (Then [`gc.get_referrers`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.get_referrers) can help you try to figure out where the extra references are, though it can't find all references.)

Comment: @user2357112 I looked into using `sys.getrefcount(arr)`. I think it only gives the references to the Python object `arr`, but the issue at hand is whether there are remaining references to the underlying memory. For example, a view into a portion of the array, like `arr[0:10]`, will not manifest as an additonal reference.
Besides, `arr.resize(0, refcheck=False)` doesn't work anyway as I mentioned. I understand that this can occur if it's a view into an array, but It fails even on Fortran-ordered numpy arrays which are loaded directly from disk with `np.load(...)`.

Comment: Check the `base` and `flags` properties of your array.

Comment: If I save an `order='F'` array (that is OWNDATA), and then load it, the new file does not OWNDATA.  It's the transpose of its `base`.  I can get around this by making a `copy` after loading.

Comment: @Myridium: The implementation of `np.load` returns a view in that case, though. It creates a C-ordered array, then [transposes it](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/lib/format.py#L862C24-L862C24) with `array.transpose()`, which makes a view. Generally, NumPy functions are very careful about whether or not they return a view of their input, but they don't really care about whether they return a view of a newly-allocated array.

Comment: @user2357112, I was a bit surprised to discover that sometimes advanced indexing returns a transposed view.  It seems to select values with the array indices, and transpose to handle the slices.  I suspect that's part of why mixed basic/advanced indexing has shape problems when the slices are in the middle.

Comment: @user2357112 @hpaulj - okay, so I could do `b = arr.base; del arr; b.resize(0, refcheck=True)`, but then I'd have to remove the variable `arr`, but then I woudn't be able to handle the exception when `resize` fails because I wouldn't be able to reconstruct `arr`. Unless I did some janky thing which recorded exactly what kind of view `arr` was. This seems like an oversight in `numpy`. Instead of `array = array.transpose()` in the `np.load(...)` method, why is it not `array.strides = array.strides[::-1]`? That only works for square arrays unfortunately.

Comment: @hpaulj - I can't make a copy. Memory is not infinite.

Comment: One would expect `np.require(arr, requirements=['OWNDATA'])` to produce a view with `OWNDATA` true, but it creates a copy, even on square arrays where I can do a better job with `array.strides = array.strides[::-1]`. So it really seems like an oversight in `numpy`.

Comment: @Myridium: "A view with `OWNDATA`" is a contradiction. A view is an array that provides access to another object's data - it doesn't own that data. `ndarray.resize` is a dangerous, extremely niche tool that fits very poorly with how the rest of NumPy is designed - the devs don't really care about jumping through the hoops necessary to make sure routines that can output `OWNDATA` arrays do so, or documenting whether the output of every function owns its data.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** This is not intended as a correct answer - rather a quick and dirty idea to raise discussion.

First thing that comes to mind is accessing the standard C `free` function through `ctypes`, passing the pointer of the original array to `process_big_array`, then freeing it when needed.

Absolutely no clue how this would interact with gc, and I'd imagine this will lead to horrible side-effects or segfaults in almost every possible situation.

Thoughts?

```py
import os
import ctypes
import psutil
import resource
import numpy as np

# Import C free(), limit memory of process to 1 GB for the sake of example
libc = ctypes.CDLL("libc.so.6")
MAX_MEM = int(1024 ** 3)
resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_AS, (MAX_MEM, MAX_MEM)) # Limit m
memory_used = lambda : psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss / 1024 ** 2

def process_big_array_free(array, reference):
    big_intermediate_arr_1 = array * 2
    print(f"First op {memory_used():.2f} MB")
    libc.free(reference)
    print(f"After free() {memory_used():.2f} MB")
    big_intermediate_arr_2 = big_intermediate_arr_1 * 3
    print(f"Second op {memory_used():.2f} MB")
    big_output_array = big_intermediate_arr_1 + big_intermediate_arr_2
    print(f"Third op {memory_used():.2f} MB\n")
    return big_output_array


def process_big_array(array):
    big_intermediate_arr_1 = array * 2
    print(f"First op {memory_used():.2f} MB")
    big_intermediate_arr_2 = big_intermediate_arr_1 * 3
    print(f"Second op {memory_used():.2f} MB")
    big_output_array = big_intermediate_arr_1 + big_intermediate_arr_2
    print(f"Third op {memory_used():.2f} MB")
    return big_output_array


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(f"On startup {memory_used():.2f} MB")
    # Create 160 MB bytearray
    big_array = np.ones(160 * 1024**2, dtype=np.uint8)
    reference = big_array.ctypes._as_parameter_
    print(f"Allocate big_array {memory_used():.2f} MB")
    # Run function with free() on intermediate arrays, works
    output = process_big_array_free(big_array, reference)
    assert output.mean() == 8.0
    del output, big_array

    big_array = np.ones(160 * 1024**2, dtype=np.uint8)
    # Run same function without freeing, crashes due to MemoryError
    output = process_big_array(big_array)
```

```
>>> On startup 31.21 MB
>>> Allocate big_array 191.73 MB
>>> First op 351.86 MB
>>> After free() 191.94 MB
>>> Second op 351.69 MB
>>> Third op 511.70 MB
>>> 
>>> On 2nd call 32.03 MB
>>> First op 351.79 MB
>>> Second op 511.80 MB
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 46, in <module>
    output = process_big_array(big_array)
  File "test.py", line 29, in process_big_array
    big_output_array = big_intermediate_arr_1 + big_intermediate_arr_2
numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate 160. MiB
```

Comment: That's great, thanks for showing me this! I'm going to go with `hpaulj`'s answer because it's probably safer, and I won't have to locate the libc DLL or fiddle with pointers manually. It's useful to know that the array pointer can be accessed with `big_arr.ctypes._as_parameter_`. Though since it's a hidden variable, that API could change, so it's dangerous to use.

Comment: Agreed, `hpaulj`'s version is probably equally dangerous when it comes to side-effects, but has a lot less extra hassle. The `refcheck=False` "hack" is nifty!

Comment: If you *really* wanted to, you could also just work with C-like arrays directly by allocating memory using `ctypes` and using `np.frombuffer` for numpy operations. This would bypass the need for this reference trickery altogether, but then you might as well port your code entirely to C. The approach presented by `user2357112` seems the most pythonic and easiest to implement.

Comment: I want the user to be able to input a numpy array, to acknowledge that its contents will be destroyed/mutated, and to handle the rest inside the function. Unfortunately, no proposed solution works so far. user2357112's solution can still leave dangling references, and demands that the user of the function worry about memory management. The `refcheck=False` trick actually doesn't work (see my comment on that answer). Your last suggestion would require the user to pass a `ctypes` buffer or something other than a numpy array. The goal is to package the function so that it accepts a numpy array.

Comment: If your application fails on a system with 1 TB of RAM due to memory limitations, I'd argue that user-friendliness is the least of your concerns XD Jokes aside, if you're willing to bend a little on good python principles, you can just define `big_array` as `global`, and call `process_big_array` without parameters, deleting the array whenever. I don't think this can be done in a robust, clean way without writing a C-extension for `ndarray`.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your advice and for showing me the `ctypes` stuff. Most aspects of the code have been optimized, and I'm in the packaging stage. Not all users will be working on such big data. I want to conform to principles of good program design, i.e. encapsulation. I don't care how messy things are under the hood, as long as they are robust and I can present a clean, documented interface to the user of the module API. Perhaps this will evenutally serve as my entry point to writing a C-extension, so thanks for that suggestion.